# Flutter + Firebase: How to implement 'Google Sign In'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement 'Google SignIn' in my project as an authentication method, using Flutter and Firebase.

I tried watching some tutorials on Youtube, but they're all outdated (I guess...) because they don't work and there is documentation only for ios and android not for flutter.

Can someone please explain, maybe with an example at best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Working method:-

```
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final FirebaseUser _user;

void signInwithGoogle()async
{
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
          await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );
     await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    _user=await _auth.currentUser();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create a Firebase project and integrate it with your Flutter project [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)
2. Make sure that you have the latest version on pub.dev [for example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core)
3. You can try [this tutorial](https://blog.codemagic.io/firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-using-flutter/)
4. **Very important** to add to `ios/Runner/Info.plist` the reverse app id if you want it to work on iOS ([tutorial](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#ios-integration))
5. **Very Important** to add SHA1 and SHA256 in the Android app configuration on Firebase